# Cannot Display Google Map in JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As part of an assignment we have to use the Google Map API to generate a map and add customer markers ETC. However, when adding this to my current webpage, it does not generate a map and only comes up with the screenshot below.

http://i.gyazo.com/81bccf77e78681f0f9d71c2abe254b58.png

```
//JavaScript GoogleMaps Manager
window.addEventListener ( 'load', initialise);

//Beginning of Function
function initialise()
    {
        //Specify new variable for lat and long manually
        var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng (53.8319, -2.984547-1.7656)

        //Specify variable for map options
        var mapOptions = 
        {
            center: latLong,
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        //Using DOM to find div in HTML and use it
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById ( 'mapArea' );   
        var map = new google.maps.Map ( mapContainer, mapOptions );
    }
```

This is the code used to generate the map. It worked outside of the website, in it's own index file with no other divs or code, but I cannot get it to generate properly within the website I have to design.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check that your container has a height and width set for it, either on the element itself, or in CSS.

Comment: @Andy They do, it displays for a second when you refresh using ctrl+f5 then disappears though, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is drawing a map to the container, but doesn't know where to tile it.

It looks like your latlng call is weird:
`var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng (53.8319, -2.984547-1.7656)`

long of `-2.984547-1.7656` ? which ends up being `-4.750147`

I'm guessing that's the problem, that latlng ends up in the middle of the ocean, where there's no road tiles:
[Google Map link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B049'54.8%22N+4%C2%B045'00.5%22W/@53.8356562,-4.7505744,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0)

Comment: Yeah, that was my error, removed it to no avail. Still doesn't display it though.

Comment: It seems like `var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng (53.8319, -2.984547)` would work.

Also, if you liked my answer, please select it as 'accepted', if it worked out for you! if not, let's find out why!

Comment: Here's a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ynsy6Ly6/2/ using your code from above. Does it help?

Comment: I feel like there could be something in my existing layout breaking it as using the fiddle code displays this http://gyazo.com/7b156ca5890242a3d17c644c65b70dd4

Comment: ah, my fault. I called the function `initialize()`, and I bet your code is still calling `window.addEventListener ( 'load', initialise);` try replacing the z with an s :)

Comment: Still getting the grey box, although I can see if briefly when I refresh http://gyazo.com/45eed7ac395816c484d582eb3e2e7bdc

Comment: is anything happening to the `map` variable after initialisation?

Comment: I'm not overly great at JS and debugging it, how would I go about checking that?

Comment: Can you post the JS/HTML you're actually using?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/c3137abb3eda022053ac5b3a9896c25e
http://gyazo.com/5001e332ed86262c66f6ccbe4dbbb533
HTML + JS, sorry for taking a while to respond.